# Ansible synchronize always prepend username@host

Tags: ansible, rsync

I'm running an ansible 2.3.1.0 on my local machine (macOs) and trying to achieve :

- connecting to `user1@host1`
- copying a file from `user2@host2:/path/to/file` to `user1@host1:/tmp/path/to/file`

### I'm on my local, with `host1` as `hosts` and `user1` as `remote_user`:

```
- synchronize: mode=pull src=user2@host2:/path/to/file dest=/tmp/path/to/file
```

### Wrong output:

```
/usr/bin/rsync (...) user1@host1:user2@host2:/path/to/file /tmp/path/to/file
```

### Conclusion

I've been trying different options. I've debugged `ansible`. I can't understand what's wrong.

Help!

## Edit 1

I've also tried adding `delegate_to`:

```
- synchronize: mode=pull src=/path/to/file dest=/tmp/path/to/file 
  delegate_to: host2
```

It gives:

```
fatal: [host1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

And also:

```
- synchronize: mode=pull src=/path/to/file dest=/tmp/path/to/file 
  delegate_to: user2@host2
```

Which gives:

```
fatal: [host1 -> host2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L host1:/path/to/file /tmp/path/to/file", "failed": true, "msg": "Permission denied (publickey).\r\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]\nrsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]\n", "rc": 255}
```

NB: `ssh user1@host1` and then `ssh user2@host2` works with ssh keys (no password required)

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to this notes from [modules' docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html):

> For the synchronize module, the “local host” is the host the synchronize task originates on, and the “destination host” is the host synchronize is connecting to.
>
> The “local host” can be changed to a different host by using delegate_to. This enables copying between two remote hosts or entirely on one remote machine.

I guess, you may want to try (assuming Ansible can connect to host2):

```
- synchronize:
    src: /path/to/file
    dest: /tmp/path/to/file
  delegate_to: host2
```

Comment: I've tried this also, see edit. I've downvoted because I did pay attention to this note.

Comment: You've added vital piece of information: you can't connect to host2 from ansible host, only via host1. `synchronize` module can operate only between `localhost<->current_remote_host` or `delegated_host<->current_remote_host`. So you either need to make host2 accessible by ansible (to make it work as delegate_to host) or just use `rsync` with `command` module on host1.

Comment: I can `ssh user2@host2` from both `localhost` and `host1`, yet it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have `host2` with `user2` in your Ansible inventory?

Comment: Nope, should I?

Comment: `delegate_to: host2` wouldn't work without it (I guess this is why you have perm denied).

Comment: It's too much of a hassle and poorly documented, I'd better use the FTP module. Thanks for the help!